# Python. Как передать в логи некоторые дополнительные параметры

Tags: python, логирование

У меня есть некоторый модуль, который отвечает за логирование. Я инициализирую его в ранере.

```
import logging
from logging import config as logging_config
from utils.logger.logging_config import login_conf

logging_config.dictConfig(login_conf)
logger = logging.getLogger('some_log_client')

def main():
    # some code here
    logger.info('some log message with data task_id= %s, project_id = %s', 2, 3)
```

Конфигурационный файл:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)-4d - %(message)s"
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "default"
        },
        "graylog_gelf": {
            "class": "pygelf.GelfTcpHandler",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 8000,
            "formatter": "default"
        },

    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": [
                "console",
            ],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False
    }
```

Как можно избавиться от харкода в этой части лога и передать их как дополнительные параметры :

```
logger.info('some log message with data task_id= %s, project_id = %s', 2, 3)
# ___________________________________________^ _____________^
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Ну так и передавайте их как параметры, так же как  `2, 3` : `logger.info('some log message with data %s = %s, %s = %s', 'task_id', 2, 'project_id', 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я уж написал в комментарии к вопросу, что все элементы сообщения можно передавать как параметры, так же как 2, 3 :

```
logger.info('some log message with data %s = %s, %s = %s', 'task_id', 2, 'project_id', 3)
```

Однако подумал, что не плохо было бы указать на такую вещь, как форматтер. Чтобы не выдумывать, взял пример у [Типпетта](https://medium.com/better-programming/power-up-your-python-logging-6dd3ed38f322):

```
logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")
consoleHandle = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandle.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# Setup the formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
consoleHandle.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandle)
logger.info("Message")

>>> 2019-10-25 00:01:42,283 - __main__ - INFO - Message
```